# Boot from SD but use a thumb drive as RootFS

Tags: usb, sd-card, storage, filesystem

How would I make my RPi boot from the SD card, then immediately direct to my thumb drive (USB/Flash Disk) to run the Root FileSystem. I need to do this because I will be doing some quite heavy storage stuff on my RPi and I need more space, thus I'm moving to the thumb drive.
How would I (step-by-step please) be able to do such thing?

Comment: While this isn't too hard, two questions first: do you have another unix (linux, OSX) at hand and more importantly why move the rootfs? Does 'heavy storage' imply you also need the speed or is it just about 'more space'? In the latter case it would be a lot easier to just mount the usb drive someplace and leave the root where it is.

Comment: @Max I do have another Unix system at hand. And I'm moving it primarily because of space but also because of speed. The reason why Im moving it, is because I only really use command line, and doesnt matter where i look I find how to mount the thumb drive but at the same time can't figure out how to use it so it stores packages downloaded with apt-get. If you could tell me how to use it for packages without have to swap the disks because it'd decrease my SD card's life, I'd appreciate it. Otherwise show me how to do as I asked above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than moving the whole root partition, you could create a partition on the USB stick, and then pick a mount point for this where the space is required.  For example, if you needed more space for downloaded apt packages, which live in `/var/cache` then you could mount the new partition on `/var` meaning that everything under this path would be stored in the USB drive.

Basically you need to:

1. Create a partition on the USB stick (This is well documented), and format that partition, for example `# mke2fs -j /dev/sdb1` to create an ext3 partition, assuming the USB device is `/dev/sdb`
2. Mount it in a temporary location, and copy the existing contents of `/var` to that location.  Something like:

   `# mkdir /mnt/temp`

   `# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/temp`

   `# mv -v /var/* /mnt/temp`

   `# umount /mnt/temp`
3. Set up an entry in `/etc/fstab` so that the file system is mounted at boot time.  Something like this would work:

   `/dev/sdb1  /var    ext3    defaults    0 0`
4. Reboot the RaspberryPi, and when the system starts up `/var` should be on the external partition.  You can verify this with the `mount` or `df` commands.